# Size Of Paging File

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory, disk-space, pagefile

Why is paging size necessary and why does it balloon now and then. 
I am using Core 2 Quad. With Windows 7 Professional x32 and 4 GB RAM, still the paging file size is huge near 2.96 GB in C drive.

Moreover, C drive size decreases from time to time. Even if I clean up temporary and other files using CCleaner utility, the freed disk space is not visible/available until I restart my computer.

Kinldy guide!

Comment: What is the size of your C drive?

Comment: On a system with 4GB of ram a page file that is only 3GB is kinda small.

Comment: @venomrld  The size of C drive 50 GB

Comment: @ Zoredache well I also realise this but that still does not explain how the disk space is consumed at one instance and I have to restart to re claim drive space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out for malware activity on your C: drive. Once it also happened to my system:

A file winsta.exe was residing in the "C:\Windows\system32" directory. At startup everything seemed fine, but after a few minutes or so the file expanded its size to the full available disk space (Mine was 100 GB!).

Similar activity is likely going on in your system. Simply search for all files and sort them. Though this is a tedious job, but still may help. 
You may also consider recording the size of your directories at startup, and then again when the system starts conjesting up.

Solution: Let your file be infectedfile.exe.
Create a folder in the same directory as the file with the same name (infectedfile.exe). It simply avoids creation of the file. Be sure to delete the file at startup as soon as possible.